# How to code a video-preview for an embedded video link?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api

I want to make a video preview of an embedded video link.

So basically on mouseover it will give a thumbnail preview. 
and on mouseout it will reset to the original thumbnail.

How would you code something for this embed link: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bxQgs_kx2Mc" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>` or a link from another site.

Comment: Are you using youtube embedded video generated from youtube or you actually use API to fetch video?

Answer (score 0):

There is many solution to this.
Usually you will have prepared .gif image which you can use as a poster(not an actual poster attr) to overlay over the video. Then you will show it and hide it on mousein and mouseout, youtube in does it like that.

But you can also do something like this. See full example here --> https://codepen.io/nikolamitic/pen/GyMrqx

```
var figure = $(".video").hover( hoverVideo, resetVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function resetVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).load(); 
}
```

So you would play video on mouseIn (here actually hover) and stop(actually load) video on mouseout.

If you provide more details the answer could be more specific to your case.

Comment: Thank you, but do you think you try an xvideos embed link? I am trying to make an adult website and this would be very useful for me. Intead of the previwe playing the video from start to finish, would it be possible to make it display parts of the video, like a gif?